# How to calculate projected vs actual rewards for delegators using Tzscan API?

Tags: baking, delegating

We are building a delegator dashboard,

I was wondering how can we calculate projected vs actual rewards using the Tzscan API?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain, if you want to do the calculation by yourself or do you want to pull the already calculated results from tzscan?

Answer (score 5):

**Solution Part 1:**

How to calculate actual rewards using the tzscan.io API?

One of the first payout scripts using the tzscan API was released and published in [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tezosdelegate/comments/9fnzsa/improved_paypy_script_for_small_bakers/?utm_source=reddit-android). It is licensed under MIT and it is a Python script which is very easy to understand and short. Here are some code snippets:

```
# TzScan API URLs
api_url_head = 'https://api{}.tzscan.io/v2/head'.format(api_mirror) # info about current status
api_url_rewards = 'http://api{}.tzscan.io/v2/rewards_split/'.format(api_mirror) # info about rewards at specific cycle

# get current cycle info
response = urllib.request.urlopen(api_url_head)
data = json.loads(response.read())

####################
# get rewards data #
####################
page = 0
response = urllib.request.urlopen('{}{}?cycle={}&number=50&p={}'.format(api_url_rewards, baker_address, cycle, page))
data = json.loads(response.read())

print('\n')

total_delegators = int(data['delegators_nb'])
if total_delegators == 0:
    print('No non-baker delegators for cycle ', format(cycle), '.')

pages = total_delegators / 50

paid_delegators = 0

total_staking_balance = int(data['delegate_staking_balance'])
```